# Rollup Summary field is deleted, but the dependency still exist

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have created two objects School and Teacher.
School fields - School name, location, pincode.
Teacher fields - Teacher name, salary (number datatype), qualification.

Now i created a rollup summary field for max salary in School object.
It created successfully and working fine. Now i wanted to change the datatype of salary from number to currency. It was not allowing me to change the datatype of salary as it was a rollup summary field in School object. So i deleted the rollup summary field in School object. It deleted successfully. 
But still i am not able to change the datatype of salary, it still shows the error :[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you clicked on the delete link, you would have seen this pop-up message:

> After you've deleted this field, it appears in the deleted components
>   list for 15 days. During that time, you can either undelete it to
>   restore the field and all data stored in it, or delete the field
>   permanently. Note that when you undelete a field, some properties on
>   the field will be lost or changed. After 15 days, the field and its
>   data are permanently deleted.
>
> You will have 15 days to undelete this field to restore the field and
>   all data stored in it, and after that time it and all data stored in
>   it will be automatically permanently deleted.

So it was actually 'soft' deleted.

You need to switch to Salesforce Classic to find your deleted components.
Go to **Setup** | **Object** | *{Your Object Name}* | **Fields**. 
Find it at the bottom of the table.
And then delete it permanently from there.